# Combinatorial Necklaces & Strips of $n$ Beads and $k$ Colours

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, necklace-and-bracelets

Say I have $n$ indistinguishable beads and $k$ different colours. Suppose here and for the rest of the writeup that $k \mid n$ unless otherwise stated.

I want to colour all the $n$ beads using exactly $k$ colours, such that each colour is used exactly $n \over k$ times. For the purpose of this question, rotations that result from the same initial configuration are considered the same, whereas reflections are considered distinct.

1. In how many ways can this be done if I am to form a **strip**?
2. In how many ways can this be done if I am to form a **necklace**?
3. It is more of a general question, but is there any rule of thumb / way of thinking / mathematical formulation, that transforms a combinatorial "line" question to a "loop" question? I.E, asking questions 1 & 2, with same rule of rotations/reflections, but about a different set of configurations.

***My progress so far:***

The initial textbook question was formatted differently, but imagining it as necklaces and beads finally led me to search the right keywords and I found what I believe to be the correct approach to this problem. [This wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)) seems to be talking exactly about that. The $N_k(n)$ , $L_k(n)$ , $B_k(n)$ are different countings of the necklaces under slightly different rules. Formulas are given for each, using common number-theoretical functions.

All $3$ functions allow $k \nmid n$ cases. $B_k(n)$ uses PET  to count reflections as equivalent as well, and thus isn't what I am looking for. To my understanding, $N_k(n)$ allows any number of colours up to $k$ to be used, again not quite my goal. But The $L_k(n)$ formula seems promising, as it counts the configurations using **exactly** $k$ colours. The difference is that $L_k(n)$ counts $1$ red bead, $2$ yellow beads and $3$ green beads as a valid configuration (because it uses 3 colours), whereas my question deems it invalid, as it uses each colour a different number of times. I believe a modification to it can answer my original question but I cannot see how exactly and I also might be wrong.

Fortunately, the wikipedia page lists 2 examples with pictures that comply with my question rules. The $n=6 , k = 3$ case yields $16$ results. The $n=6 , k = 2$ yields $4$ results.

Also useful to watch and take results from is [this page](https://www.jasondavies.com/necklaces/), listing results and configurations of $N_k(n)$ and $B_k(n)$ for arbitrary values of $n$ and $k$.

Comment: Regarding point 3. I would approach this type of question using the Polya Enumeration Theorem, which is a generalisation of the orbit counting lemma (sometimes called Burnside's Lemma). There is a weighted and a (simpler) unweighted version of this theorem. This simple version is sufficient. Understanding this will require knowledge of permutation groups and group actions.  This description from wikipedia does a good job of explaining the theorem in the context of necklaces: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the case of necklaces we have the cycle index

$$Z(C_n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{d|n} \varphi(d) a_d^{n/d}.$$

We get with $k$ colors $Q_j$ (this is PET)

$$[Q_1^{n/k} \cdots Q_k^{n/k}]
Z\left(C_n; \sum_{j=1}^k Q_j\right)
= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{d|n} \varphi(d)
[Q_1^{n/k} \cdots Q_k^{n/k}]
\left(\sum_{j=1}^k Q_j^d\right)^{n/d}.$$

We see that $d$ must divide $n/k:$

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{d|n/k} \varphi(d)
[Q_1^{n/k} \cdots Q_k^{n/k}]
\sum_{m_1+\cdots+m_k = n/d}
{n/d\choose m_1,\ldots, m_k}
\prod_{j=1}^k Q_j^{d m_j}.$$

Here the $m_j$ are non-negative. Now we must have $d m_j = n/k$
so that $m_j = n/k/d$ and we get

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{d|n/k} \varphi(d)
\frac{(n/d)!}{(n/k/d)!^k}$$

or alternatively

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{d|n/k} \varphi(n/k/d)
\frac{(kd)!}{d!^k}.}$$

As a sanity check with just one color $k=1$ we get $\frac{1}{n}
\sum_{d|n} \varphi(n/d) = 1$, which is correct. With $k=n$ colors we get
$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{d=1} \varphi(1/d) \frac{(nd)!}{(d!)^n} = \frac{1}{n}
n! = (n-1)!$ which is correct as well. This is  [OEIS
A208183](https://oeis.org/A208183).